# How to get collection object when use where in collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I am trying to add where in collection but it return

> Varien_Db_Select Object

instead of return collection object.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('orderoutofuk/orderitem')->getCollection()->getSelect()->where('main_table.send_payment_request_date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY ');
```

and I want specific column value in array instead of looping through each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with below code it will give you collection object.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('orderoutofuk/orderitem')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("send_payment_request_date", array('gteq'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY')));
```

and then you can use `getColumnValues` function on collection to get values in form of single dimension array without looping throug each object.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('orderoutofuk/orderitem')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("send_payment_request_date", array('gteq'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY')))->getColumnValues('<YourFieldName>');
```

It will return like

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 'Your value'
    [1] => 'Your value'
)
```